# How to store OAuth2 access tokens in php?

Tags: php, hash, oauth-2.0, discord, access-token

This is my scenario. The user opens my platform's auth page and then clicks on the `Connect to Discord` button. The user will allow access from his/her discord account to my application and I get a `code`. Then I exchange the `code` for a `token` with `7 DAYS` lifetime. I have these problems

1. When should I refresh the access token exactly? For example, should I store the creation time of the token somewhere (dB or client), and every time I check if it was close to getting expired, refresh the access token? I don't want to ask the user to log in to discord every 7 days for sure.
2. Where should I store the access token for a user? Somewhere on the client-side or the dB? I mean is it secure to store the access tokens on the client-side? Isn't this better to store it for each user on the dB?
3. If I want to store the access token on the dB, I should hash it, right? How can I hash the access token and store it on the dB and decrypt it back to the access token for calling the api? (Using PHP)
4. Where should I store my application `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET`? I am using these on my `PHP` file right now. Is it secure?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 3. Hash's are not Encryptions. If you hash anything there should be NO WAY of Un-Hashing the hash

Comment: @RiggsFolly So... just storing the access token on the dB?

Comment: I would suggest store in a session. Only there for duration of the user actually playing on your system. Each time they come back you restart the Auth process. That way you are very unlikely to be the reason someones access gets released in the wild. What you dont store you cannot lose

Comment: @RiggsFolly And when the user closed the browser and I lost the session and the token, what to do now? Ask the user to give me access again?

Comment: Yes, that IMO is safer than you losing data